# Java Program - Insertion sort using For Loop

Tags: java, arrays, insertion-sort

I have written a java program for insertion sort.

```
public class InsertionSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int arr[] = { 12, 11, 13, 5, 6 };

        int len = arr.length;

        for(int i=0;i<len-1;i++) {

            for(int j=i+1;j<len;j++) {

                if(arr[j] < arr[i]) {
                    int temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i]+ " ");
        }

    }

}
```

Could you please let me know if the above program is correct and is the right way to perform insertion sorting. I'm getting  the correct output.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Best would be if you test with different inputs to make sure the program works as wished. Try with an empty array, an array with one element, with two elements (sorted and unsorted and two equal elements), arrays with more elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to print the New array after each iteration of j loop using

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr))
```

This will result in below statements with analysis as a comment
//Insertion sort start with element at index 1 since it compares left side of numbers 
 **and after each sort,  all the elements on the left side of current value will be sorted already in previous iterations**

```
[11, 12, 13, 5, 6] // correct since 11 < 12
[11, 12, 13, 5, 6] //correct since 12 < 13
[5, 12, 13, 11, 6] //5 has changed its position which is correct but also Here you can //see the position of 11 changed
[5, 12, 13, 11, 6]
[5, 12, 13, 11, 6]
[5, 11, 13, 12, 6] 
[5, 6, 13, 12, 11] 
[5, 6, 12, 13, 11]
[5, 6, 11, 13, 12]
[5, 6, 11, 12, 13]
```

Try below code

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
        int arr[] = { 12, 11, 13, 5, 6 };
        int len = arr.length;
        for(int i=1; i<len; i++) {
            int key = arr[i];
            int j = i - 1;
            for ( ; (j >= 0 && arr[j] > key); j--) { 
                arr[j + 1] = arr[j];  
            } 
            arr[j + 1] = key;
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        }
    }
```

It will give you below output

```
[11, 12, 13, 5, 6]
[11, 12, 13, 5, 6]
[5, 11, 12, 13, 6]
[5, 6, 11, 12, 13]
```

source https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-sort/

Comment: Thanks @hades for the detailed explanation. But can we use for loop instead of while to make this work. or it will only work in case of while and its the best way to implement this.

Comment: yes we can .. i will update the answer

Comment: @Kaustubh I have updated the answer with for loop, Please accept the answer if you feels it serves for you problem :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! It works :)

Answer (score 0):

It is correct but it's not Insertion Sort. You wrote Bubble Sort.

Insertion Sort looks like this:

```
public class InsertionSort {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int arr[] = { 12, 11, 13, 5, 6 };
        int len = arr.length;
        for(int i=0;i<len-1;i++) {
            int max_idx = i
            for(int j=i+1;j<len;j++) {
                if(arr[max_idx] < arr[j]) {
                    max_idx = j
                }
            }

            if (i != max_idx) {
                int temp = arr[max_idx];
                arr[max_idx] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i]+ " ");
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, Java collections have their own sort method which is way faster.